# Getting correct WKT result to 4 decimal places using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, coordinates, extents, well-known-text

I'm using PostGIS version 2.3. I want to get the SW and NE corners of a bounding box, corrected to 4 decimal places.

Right now I have this to retrieve the SW and NE corners from my geometry column:

```sql
SELECT st_astext(st_transform(st_makepoint(st_xmin(st_extent(geom)), st_ymin(st_extent(geom))), '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs ',4326)) as sw,
       st_astext(st_transform(st_makepoint(st_xmax(st_extent(geom)), st_ymax(st_extent(geom))), '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs ',4326)) as ne
FROM HOLDINGS
WHERE custname='XXX';
```

Which returns results like this:

```
                     sw                     |                     ne
--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------
 POINT(-0.685239554498251 51.4940418030595) | POINT(-0.680132974825013 51.4962802022361)
```

But how can I amend this to get the SW and NE corners corrected to 4 decimal places?

The results can be four numbers rather than two WKT POINTs (in fact that would be preferable).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113096/how-to-round-an-average-to-2-decimal-places-in-postgresql

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest way to round geometry coordinates is to use [ST_SnapToGrid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html):

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SnapToGrid('POINT(-0.685239554498251 51.4940418030595)', 0.0001));
       st_astext
-----------------------
 POINT(-0.6852 51.494)
```

But if you just need the 4 bounding coordinates, then ST_Extent returns a simple `box2d` type, which sort-of looks like WKT:

```
SELECT ST_Extent(
  ST_SnapToGrid(
    ST_Transform(geom, '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs', 4326),
    0.0001))
FROM (
  -- whatever geometry table goes here, e.g. two points
  SELECT 'POINT(123 4567)'::geometry geom
  UNION SELECT 'POINT(8910 11121314)'
) s;
               st_extent
---------------------------------------
 BOX(-15.9517 49.8078,-7.5602 89.9958)
```

(You may also want to assign an SRID for that projection in your `spatial_ref_sys` table, as ST_Transform performs faster using geometries with these set)

---

#### PostGIS 2.5 or newer

A newer method is to specify a second parameter of [ST_AsText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) to reduce the maximum number of decimal digits after floating point:

```
SELECT ST_AsText('POINT(-0.685239554498251 51.4940418030595)'::geometry, 4)
       st_astext
-----------------------
 POINT(-0.6852 51.494)
```

Answer (score 3):

And if @Mike T's answer isn't what you want, you can get the X and Y coordinates out using the [`ROUND()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_round.asp) function with something like

```
SELECT 
    round(ST_X('POINT(-0.685239554498251 51.4940418030595)'), 4),
    round(ST_Y('POINT(-0.685239554498251 51.4940418030595)'), 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone new getting here, in **PostGIS version 3.1** or newer there is a new method to achieve this:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ReducePrecision('POINT(1.412 19.323)', 0.1));
st_astext
-----------------
 POINT(1.4 19.3)
```

This method returns a valid geometry, something that can't be said for the method ST_SnapToGrid.

https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ReducePrecision.html

Answer (score 0):

I combined both answers from @AlexLeith and @MikeT.
[Here is my question with an answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321814/st-snaptogrid-doesnt-work-properly-e-g-41-94186153740355-41-94186149999999?noredirect=1#comment523796_321814)

```
ST_GeomFromText(concat(
'POINT (', 
round(ST_X(ST_SnapToGrid(centroid, 0.0000001))::numeric, 7), 
' ', 
round(ST_Y(ST_SnapToGrid(centroid, 0.0000001))::numeric, 7),
')'
), 4326);
```