# ST_SnapToGrid doesn't work properly, e.g. 41.94186153740355 -> 41.941861499999995

Tags: postgis, geometry, snapping

I'm using ST_SnapToGrid: `ST_SnapToGrid(somePoint, 0.0000001)` and I get strange result on many points, such as:

```
- POINT (21.619820510769063 41.94186153740355) -> POINT (21.6198205 41.941861499999995)  
- POINT (22.49594094391644 41.20357506925623) -> POINT (22.495940899999997 41.203575099999995)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Expecting every floating-point value to have an evenly divisible mantissa? There are just some values which can't be manifested by IEEE representation. It would be nice if `ST_AsText` had an optional precision operand, but it doesn't.

Comment: Try the floating point converter in https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html with decimal value 0.0000001 and you will see gets changed into 1.0000000116860974230803549289703369140625E-7.

Comment: See [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/11654)

Comment: Yes, I know about floating point imprecision problem.
I thought (or wrongly assumed) that it will try to round the number in such cases.
So I think what I want to do is to round all geometries to given precision in addition to SnapToGrid. Or maybe not even use it, only round the numbers. I not sure now.

Comment: you could try with a [`ST_AsTWKB`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsTWKB.html) roundtrip.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that all of the geometries that couldn't be divided by `ST_SnapToGrid` had form of `xx.xxxxxxx9999999x`, where `x` is a digit. That means, that if I want its precision to be centimetric, it's safe to treat such geometries as a number and just round it mathematically, all of them will round to the higher number.
After such process, they matched with the geometries I should get after reducing precision.
So, first I snapped the X and Y geometries separately, then rounded them and recreated geometry from concatenated string.

```
ST_GeomFromText(concat(
'POINT (', 
round(ST_X(ST_SnapToGrid(point, 0.0000001))::numeric, 7), 
' ', 
round(ST_Y(ST_SnapToGrid(point, 0.0000001))::numeric, 7),
')'
))
```

Comment: This is not a good approach, what o you recommend to lines and polygons?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I use the an other snapToGrid function:

```
geometry ST_SnapToGrid(geometry geomA, float originX, float originY, float sizeX, float sizeY);
```

see also: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html

use as originX and originY an Point near the middle of your geometry rounded to an integer

in your case: something like this:

```
select st_astext(st_snaptogrid('POINT (21.619820510769063 41.94186153740355)'::geometry,21,41,0.0000001,0.0000001));
```

with polygons or lines do something like that

```
update mytable set the_geom = st_snaptogrid(the_geom,st_x(st_centroid(the_geom))::int,st_y(st_centroid(the_geom))::int,0.01,0.01)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a PostGIS bug.  See ticket [5425](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5425).  There is a proposed fix, but  unfortunately there's no current schedule for it to be implemented.