# Create linestring from coordinate values in text array after rounding to 3 decimal points

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linestring

I have a table like;

| Id | coordinates (text[]) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"609275.485000001 4253109.911000001","609275.257 4253109.641000001"} |
| 2 | {"617784.171 4268033.896000001","617783.868 4268033.91","617783.81 4268030.305000001} |
| 3 | {"617673.968 4267299.198","617671.988 4267297.141","617686.15 4267281.898"} |

How can I create linestring for each row with coordinate pairs after rounding them to 3 decimal places in postgis?

Comment: @BERA, Coordinates column stores text array that contains x and y coordinates of each node of line.

Comment: How about `SELECT st_snaptogrid(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(' || array_to_string(coordinates, ', ', '*') ||')'), 0.001) geom`

Comment: @BERA, Thanks a lot for your answer. ST_SNAPTOGRID behaves differently while rouding the coordinate.There is a link for this problem. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321814/st-snaptogrid-doesnt-work-properly-e-g-41-94186153740355-41-94186149999999.   I am looking for a solution without st_snaptogrid, a solution using round.

Answer (score 3):

The PostGIS `GEOMETRY/GEOGRAPHY` data types store coordinates as `DOUBLE PRECISION` floating-point integer values with the full 15 digit precision. It is not necessarily given that pre-rounded values will be represented with the equal set of significant bits when converted back to e.g. `GEOMETRY`, and any calculations on these values will again get represented by all possible digits of precision!

To keep your desired precision during analysis/calculations you would indeed work with e.g. `ST_SnapToGrid`; the function cannot strip away digits, but rather guarantees that rounding to the given precision will always yield equal results (thus making calculations up to the given precision *precise*).

To actually improve on storage you'd want to update with [`ST_QuantizeCoordinates`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_QuantizeCoordinates.html); the resulting geometries will have all non-significant bits set to `0`, which has a *significant* impact on compression rate.

The effect is close to what you may expect, but again, any derived geometry result will have the full precision of digits used.

With any of these options applied, any export function accepting a precision value (`ST_AsText`, `ST_AsGeoJSON`, `ST_AsEncodedPolyline`, ...) will always return the same rounded value.

Comment: ST_QuantizeCoordinates does the job in my case ! I had same points rounded differently, so they were counted as different points while they were not. With this function, they are all rounded the same way. @geozelot if I understand well, it does not change the coordinates ? I am surprised as the number are different after applying the function. For example I don't get why POINT (343636.9000000008 6682947.599999995) is spatially equal to POINT (343636.890625 6682947.59375)

Comment: @J.Delannoy `ST_QuantizeCoordinates` does indeed change the internal representation of coordinates in that it sets the least significant bits to `0`; while using the internal storage type for calculations those points are equal, but when you request a different representation of the same (e.g. `ST_AsText`), the floating point insufficiency will get reintroduced!

Comment: thanks, you made it clearer :)